# BASH, print duplicates without sort

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day,

I was wondering how to print only the words that are repeated in a file, without sort.

The opposite in awk is: `awk '!x[$0]++'`. Is any other way?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

**Expected input**

```
a
b
a
c
d
e
f
w
g
w
h
```

**Expected output**

```
a
w
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your `awk` statement, you'll see that it negates the printing condition with `!`. Just remove that, and it'll print duplicates instead:

```
awk 'x[$0]++'
```

To just print one line per duplicate, even when they appear again:

```
awk 'x[$0]++ == 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 'G;h;/^(\S+).*\1/P' file
```

This uses a back reference to print only duplicates of the current line (in this case a single character) that occur in the file.

```
sed -rn 'G;h;/^(\S+).*\1/!b;/^(\S+).*\1.*\1/b;P' file
```

This uses back references to print only when one other occurrence of the current line (in this case a single character) occurs in the file.

Answer (score 0):

if word are on 1 word per line (or 1 sentence as 1 "word")

```
uniq -d YourFile
```

if multi word

```
tr " " "\n" YourFile | uniq -d
```

Comment: `uniq -d` will only produce the required result **if** the file is sorted first __unless__ by coincidence the results lie on successive lines.

Comment: You are right, i forget trying to first using sort -u so my file was sorted. So the question now is: "shoud/could" be the file be modified in a sort way. If not, in which place the word has to be printed (first or last occurence ordered)